# ¿Cómo hacer un chat P2P con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Siempre me he preguntado qué clase de tecnología tengo que usar para enviar información desde una ventana hacia las demás. Recientemente he hecho las siguientes funciones:

```
net=new WebSocket("ws://tatopatato.esy.es")
```

Esta función no crea un server WebSocket, pero sí lo recibe, aunque siempre daba error hasta que probé a hacerlo con una URL de html5 Rocks. No daba error, pero tampoco detectaba los mensajes del WebSocket. Probé esta otra función:

```
net=new webkitRTCPeerConnection({'iceServers':[{'url':'stun:stun.example.org'}]})
net.onmessage=function(e){console.log(e.data)}
```

Pero resulta que esta función no está preparada para hacer una conexión P2P, solo está preparada para detectar la webcam y transferirla. Ninguna de las dos funciones se adapta a esta pregunta:
¿Qué hago para que se pueda activar una función en una de las ventanas de manera que todas las ventanas que se hayan abierto ese mismo archivo hagan todas una función? (Incluida en la que se activó la función).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En un archivo.html NO SE PUEDE HACER UN SERVIDOR P2P, PORQUE NECESITA DE UN SERVIDOR PARA ESTABLECER UNA CONEXIÓN

Sin embargo, una solución que imitaría a un servidor P2P sería usar el siguiente servidor que hice con socket.io en heroku:
http://p2p-server-by-sentifico.herokuapp.com/
...de la siguiente forma:

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
    socket=io()
    socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
      eval(e.data)
    })
    document.onkeydown=()=>{
      socket.emit("msg",{data:prompt("Enter the msg")})
    }
    </script>
```

O intentar hacer un servidor en heroku con los siguientes ficheros:

package.json:

```
{
"name":"frozen-fortress-97232",
"version":"1.0.0",
"description":"",
"engines":{"node":"6.10.2"},
"main":"index.js",
"dependencies":{
"express":"^4.13.4",
"socket.io":"^1.4.5",
"nodejs-websocket":"^1.7.1"
},
"devDependencies":{},
"scripts":{"start":"node index.js"},
"author":"",
"license":"ISC"
}
```

index.js

```
obj={}
app=require("express")()
net=require("http").createServer(app)
app.use("/public",require("express").static(__dirname+"/public"))
net.listen(process.env.PORT||3000,()=>{console.log("Ready!")})
require("socket.io")(net,{}).sockets.on("connection",(socket)=>{
  socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
    socket.broadcast.emit("msg",{data:e.data})
  })
})
```

Alternativamente, podemos usar pubnub para poder usar más canales y que la conexión no se solape entre sí:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pubnub/3.7.7/pubnub.js"></script>
<script>
  PUBNUB_demo = PUBNUB.init({
    publish_key: 'demo',
    subscribe_key: 'demo'
  })
  
  PUBNUB_demo.subscribe({
    channel: 'demo_tutorial',
    message: (e)=>{console.log(e)}
  })
  
  document.onkeydown=(e)=>{
    PUBNUB_demo.publish({
      channel:'demo_tutorial',
      message:{"text":prompt("Enter your message.")}
    })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se pueden hacer conexiones de un navegador a otro, un navegador siempre tiene el rol de *cliente*, no de *servidor*: **no tiene implementadas las funcionalidades para recibir peticiones de conexiones, sólo puede realizarlas**.

Por tanto crear un chat P2P no es posible, **necesitas un servidor** que reciba y retransmita los mensajes.

Answer (score -1):

Una de las soluciones de Java para P2P es JXTA : https://jxta.kenai.com/

De otra forma, tendrías que utilizar Socket : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Pero luego tendrías que codificar todo el sistema P2P tu mismo. Imagino que abrir un Socket como servidor y cliente cada vez que una ventana se abre, que tenga persistencia entre los datos etc...

Comment: Socket no sirve para redes públicas, y no veo la forma de usar JXTA.

Comment: >Socket is not defined.

Comment: Te recomiendo pubnub, es mucho mejor.